# Wait for page load before downloading with WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, downloadfileasync

I have several URLs stored in a text file, each of them is a link leading to a Facebook emoji, like https://www.facebook.com/images/emoji.php/v5/u75/1/16/1f618.png

I'm trying to download these images and store them on my disk. I'm using WebClient with DownloadFileAsync, something like

```
using (var client = new WebClient())  
{
    client.DownloadFileAsync(imgURL, imgName);
}
```

My problem is even if the amount of URLs is small, say 10, some of the images are downloaded ok, some give me a file corrupt error. So I thought I needed to wait for files to be downloaded till the end and added DownloadFileCompleted event, like this

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;

class Program
{
    static Queue<string> q;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        q = new Queue<string>(new[] {
            "https://www.facebook.com/images/emoji.php/v5/u51/1/16/1f603.png",
            "https://www.facebook.com/images/emoji.php/v5/ud2/1/16/1f604.png",
            "https://www.facebook.com/images/emoji.php/v5/ud4/1/16/1f606.png",
            "https://www.facebook.com/images/emoji.php/v5/u57/1/16/1f609.png",
            "https://www.facebook.com/images/emoji.php/v5/u7f/1/16/1f60a.png",
            "https://www.facebook.com/images/emoji.php/v5/ufb/1/16/263a.png",
            "https://www.facebook.com/images/emoji.php/v5/u81/1/16/1f60c.png",
            "https://www.facebook.com/images/emoji.php/v5/u2/1/16/1f60d.png",
            "https://www.facebook.com/images/emoji.php/v5/u75/1/16/1f618.png",
            "https://www.facebook.com/images/emoji.php/v5/u1e/1/16/1f61a.png"
        });
        DownloadItem();
        Console.WriteLine("Hit return after 'finished' has appeared...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void DownloadItem()
    {        
        if (q.Any())
        {
            var uri = new Uri(q.Dequeue());
            var file = uri.Segments.Last();

            var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += DownloadFileCompleted;
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(uri, file);
        }
        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("finished");
        }
    }

    private static void DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DownloadItem();
    }
}
```

It didn't help and I decided to look closer into the files that are corrupted.

It appeared that the files that were corrupted were not actually image files, but HTML pages, which either had some redirection JavaScript code to an image or were full HTML pages saying that my browser was not supported.

So my question is, how do I actually wait that an image file has been fully loaded and is ready to be downloaded?

**EDIT** I have also tried to remove the `using` statement, but that did not help either.

Comment: Might not be related to your current problem, but you're kicking off an async process and then *disposing* of the object you've started that async  process with (via the `using` statement). I'd look to improve your object management here so that you don't `Dispose` of your `WebClient` until you're actually done. Whilst you're still trying to get basics right, I'd probably suggest ignoring async for now.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Tried that without async as well, but that downloads only one file (probably missing something here). About removing the using statement - that was not helpful, see my comment below.

Comment: Just adding that edit isn't nearly as useful as providing the [mcve] I requested before.

Comment: Well that still isn't a [mcve], is it? It's not something we can copy, paste, compile, run and see the problem. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I have updated the code again. Now all one needs to do is create a Console Application and add a public class to it. The code from Main calls the Class1's method 'Call'.

Comment: It's not clear why you haven't included the class declaration and the using directives, and put it all into one... why make it harder for people to help you? I'm trying to do that now - are you happy for me to edit your question afterwards?

Comment: @Jon Skeet You're free to do it of course. Sorry that's my first try at providing a minimal, complete example of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing's being corrupted by your download - it's simply Facebook deciding (sometimes, which is odd) that it doesn't want to serve the image to your client.

It looks like it's the lack of a user agent that causes the problem. All you need to do is specify the user agent, and that looks like it fixes it:

```
webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; http://example.org/)");
```

Comment: Wow I am testing it now on a bigger amount and it does work. Thanks a lot for you help! I would never have guessed this myself.

Comment: @tube-builder it is an answer from a person who's a legend of sorts. It is bound to work. :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts

Comment: @Atul Yeah I'm aware of that :)